# Weighting based on two numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have **Number of Calls** and **Total Call Duration** per operator.

I would like to **rank/weight based on two figures**.

Is there any easy formula to do this and anyone knows how to weigt two figures?

[image]

Comment: Could you mock up some data and expected outcome?  A picture sometimes is easier to understand.

Comment: To add to Scott's comment, sure, you can rank or weight two factors.  Ranking and weighting are different, and there are an infinite number of ways to do that.  You need to decide on how.  So also include your thinking on how you envision this working.

Comment: Added an image.

Comment: I'm interested in where this data set comes from. In call centres I'm familiar with, the best performance would be highest number of calls and lowest call duration, i.e. the exact opposite of what you've said.

Comment: Weighting implies that each factor has a weight (could be equal weights).  You combine the factors to minimize or maximize the composite result.  It might help to give a name to what you are trying to optimize.

Comment: Darren - either way is fine for now,  idea is to analyse this info in every possible manner.

Comment: Fixer1234 - based on the best and worst performace (mentioend on image) rest of the operators can be assigned ranking/weightage.  I agreed, this might be very simple analysis but due to my limited excel knowledge and analytical thinking i've posted it here.

Comment: An additional thing to consider: are all operators handling the same mix of calls?  For example, if difficult calls gravitate to certain operators, you would expect those to take longer.  Two additional factors that might make the result more useful: difficulty (if the mix is different), and success rate (an operator can zip through lots of calls if they aren't solving anything or adding value to the process).

Comment: Fixer1234 - I know.  But for now let's just stick with this data as it is.

Comment: Based on the image, I'm not sure if weighting is what you're describing.  How many calls they can handle is related to the call duration.  But a simple ratio could give an operator a high or low rating if they handle a bunch of calls in a short time and then do nothing for the rest of the day.  It seems like the kind of measure you want would be to normalize the number of calls to a uniform or standard total call duration.  Say your total duration is hh:mm:ss.  Pick a standard interval, maybe an 8 hr day.  Multiply the call count by the fraction 8 / total duration, (cont'd)

Comment: so if someone had a total duration of 16 hours, their standardized call volume would be half of their recorded number.  That puts everyone on an equal basis of what they accomplished in a similar time.  If duration is more important, do the reverse--normalize total duration on a standard number of calls.

Comment: One other thought: Your example seems to value average time per call.  Rather than a product of the two numbers, this would be total duration divided by number of calls, which would reduce everything to a single number that could then be ranked.

Comment: The previously mentioned approaches combine two related numbers.  If you wanted to weight the factors independently to combine them, it would be in the form of factor1 x weight1 + factor2 x weight2.  The numbers are very different magnitudes, so one would swamp the other.  The factors would contain two parts: the variable in your table x a normalization factor to produce numbers in a similar range. The weight represents the importance you place on that factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT to return the rank of average call duration:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C2/B2<$C$2:$C$16/$B$2:$B$16))+1
```

[image]

Comment: This is literally what was asked in the question, but the resulting number doesn't really have any meaning or represent anything useful.

Comment: @fixer1234 I can only answer what the OP asks, I cannot assume the intentions.  It would be easy to use this formula in conditional formatting to highlight the rows that are the best and the worst.  But again I would be assuming that is what the OP wants.  I just answer the questions.

Comment: Perfect!  thanks Scott - Could you please explain this as well.

Comment: It basically counts how many people have a higher average phone call time.  The one with the longest average call duration would not have any greater so it would return 0, we want it to be 1 so we add 1 to what is returned by the sumproduct.